# import ES6 modules in Angular2 served by Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I would like to use ES6 Modules with Angular2 in an app that is served by Node.js and Express.js.  However, when I try to load an Angular2/ES6 app in the browser, the following is printed in the FireFox console:

```
The stylesheet http://localhost:8080/boot.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css". localhost:8080
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module vendor.js:1:0
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module boot.js:1:0
```

The problem seems to be the result of something missing from the build of the Angular2 app that is done by the Node.js/Express.js server that serves the Angular2 app.

Specifically, the problem emerged after I deleted the entire `public` app folder from [this GitHub AngularJS 1.x sample app](https://github.com/scotch-io/node-todo/tree/master/public) and replaced it with a copy of the entire `client` app folder from [this GitHub Angular2 example app](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/tree/master/client). When I then started the Express.js server with `nodemon server.js` and typed `http : // localhost : 8080` into FireFox, the console printed out the errors shown above.

I would like to get the Angular2 app running in the browser so that I can then manually start stepping through the work of re-creating the Node.js routes and resolving other errors one by one in order to get the Angular2 app to work with the Node.js/Express.js server.

**What specific changes need to be made so that these initial errors due to ES6 imports are resolved when [this Angular2 app](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/tree/master/client) is placed inside the `public` folder of [this Node.js/Express.js instance](https://github.com/scotch-io/node-todo/tree/master/public)?**

Comment: How are you building the client side part of the app? Are you gulping it? Are you running Babel in some other way? Without any details about your actual build process it's impossible to help. The client part of the Ang2 app is just the source; not the packaged app.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am not building it at all.  Part of this exercise involves learning how to do things like that.  The source app linked in the OP has an example build using Babel and Gulp.  But I do not know how to extract only the salient aspects of that to solve this problem.  Do you have suggestions?

Comment: You need all the client code. the gulpfile (if you're going to use gulp), the relevant parts of the package.json, etc. You're asking for a detailed analysis of a complete app and its build system. How about this instead: get that repo and get it running as-is. Then start pulling the client build process into your own app once you know enough to know what's relevant and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I just check out those two repos, and then do the same thing you mentioned above.

the problem is that the `client` folder of angular2 is written is ES6 syntax.

I don't think currently we can run this code on the browser without problem and

you can tell from the repo that it uses `babel` to compile the code

so if you want to use its `client` code, just make sure you also do the same

compile stuff as it does. I think everything should work

### update

What I am trying to say is the angular repo use `babel` and `gulp` to help it

transpile the code from ES6 to ES5.

You can run `gulp serve` under `angular2-esnext-starter` and it will generate one

new folder called `dist` [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEnol.png)

copy the `client` folder under that `dist` folder to `node-todo` and remember

rename it to `public` and you will see everything is ok.

so the hint is copy the `gulpfile` of `angular2-esnext-starter` and don't forget

to add more dependencies to your `package.json` should solve your problem.

[my workable node-todo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNX3O.png)

Comment: The source app linked in the OP very clearly shows that ES6 can very certainly be used in Angular2 apps.  The OP asks what relevant aspects of the source app's build need to be transferred to the destination app in order to resolve this problem.  Your response does not answer this OP.

Comment: @FirstOfMany Nobody said ES6 can't be used as the original source, but it won't run in your browser. You have to build it.